# Inspecting XAML in Windows 8 Store Apps / VS2012

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm looking for a way to inspect running XAML in a Windows 8 store app. Essentially, I want firebug / chrome inspector style functionality where I can look at the XAML source generated at runtime, to debug simple layout and style issues.

I've tried Snoop, Pistachio and WPF Inspector but none work for Windows Store apps. The only one I can find which seems to work for Store apps is XAML Spy, which is €90. I can't justify that cost.

Is there any other way to inspect running XAML?

Comment: XAML Spy is the only one I have found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [VisualTreeDebugger](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/065e2509f66f#WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging/VisualTreeDebugger.cs) class from WinRT XAML Toolkit is what you could use if you want a free tool. It doesn't do as much as XAML Spy, but you get what you pay for. I thought of adding more features to it like actual visualization of what you debug, but the work required would not justify the time investment + I didn't want to step on Koen Zwikstra's turf. I am sure he is doing a great job on that tool. Anyways - VisualTreeDebugger is enough for me, so maybe it would also be enough for you.

The way you can use it is add the class to your code, add a reference in your XAML like

```
xmlns:debug="WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging"
```

then put a hook on a control where you would like to start debugging, like

```
debug:VisualTreeDebugger.BreakOnLoaded="True"
```

which will dump the core visual tree details as text in your debugger output window (Ctrl+W,O) and break in the code that dumped your tree where you can investigate the "path" variable, which contains the list of all visual tree elements from the debugged control to the root, so you can watch their values if what you need wasn't already dumped in the output window.

Other options include

```
debug:VisualTreeDebugger.BreakOnTap="True"
debug:VisualTreeDebugger.BreakOnLayoutUpdated="True"
debug:VisualTreeDebugger.BreakOnLoaded="True"
debug:VisualTreeDebugger.TraceOnTap="True"
debug:VisualTreeDebugger.TraceOnLayoutUpdated="True"
debug:VisualTreeDebugger.TraceOnLoaded="True"
```

Since it is source code and really a single simple class - you can easily add additional things to the code to do any custom debugging you need.

Answer (score 6):

WinRT XAML Toolkit now has an actual visual - visual tree debugger.

Get it from NuGet: nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.Debugging then call `WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging.DC.ShowVisualTree()` to display the debugger tool inside of your app. It's the third option so now you can use

- the `WinRTXAMLToolkit.Debugging.VisualTreeDebugger` class - that enables you to debug the tree in your Visual Studio
- XAML Spy - which is a great commercial visual tree debugger that runs in a separate window
- and now this visual tree debugger in the WinRT XAML Toolkit that works inside of your app.

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best because XAML Inspector is not available until next year (and we don't know for sure if it remains free). Just one niggly issue is they didn't sign their debug assembly! So you have to disable signing of your project to use it. Somebody already opened an issue, please go there to vote it up so it gets attention/fixed: https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/792

Comment: I've modified the debugging library to build as release with the Nuget package release version 1.5.3.8. Check if that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

XAML Spy is what you need. You find it at http://xamlspy.com.

Comment: Did you read the question? I did mention XAML Spy by name, and I said I can't justify the cost.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Haven't found any other tools that gives you what you're looking for regarding Windows Store. I believe that you can get a free trial.

Comment: On the other hand - XAML Spy is indeed what you need. I haven't heard of anything else for WinRT either, unless you could do with just text dump and hooks into visual tree - then you could use WinRT XAML Toolkit...

Comment: also XAML Spy has a trial period, that you can use if it is a one time shot :) thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks. After 3 months of WinRT development I realized I was wasting a lot of time tweaking the XAML through trial-and-error, and that I needed a *good* XAML inspector. Through long experience I've learned that for any small price it's safest to just go straight to a commercial product. They work better, install better, and they are maintained. So, I got XAML Spy and it's doing all that I want, and more. It runs very nicely with WinRT. In one day it's already paid for itself by helping me crack a hard UI problem. It exposes parts of the XAML tree that I didn't even know were there.

Answer (score 3):

there is a new free tool called XAML Inspector. It's available through NuGet. Just search for "xamlinspector" or get if from the project page: [www.xamlinspector.com](http://www.xamlinspector.com)

[image]

Greetings
Christian