# In a Windows Store App, how do you tell which style is in use?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

In WPF you could use Snoop to see which style was affecting a control. Is there any way to know which style is affecting a control in a Windows Store App?

Comment: see if this is of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817892/inspecting-xaml-in-windows-8-store-apps-vs2012

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it does : ) Should I close this question because of its similarity?

Comment: It will probably be closed as a duplicate, but you can delete it if you want.